# Unset Environment Variable in Mac

Tags: mac, bash

On Linux I can unset an environment variable (not set it to an empty string, actually remove it using the `--unset` flag like this:

```
$ env --unset=DATABASE_URL rake assets:precompile
```

This same command does not work on a mac. What is the equivalent mac command?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know current versions of Mac OS X use `bash` as the default shell. In `bash` and other Bourne-compatible shells you can use `unset` built-in command:

```
unset DATABASE_URL
```